# Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'void'

Tags: typescript, express, asynchronous, try-catch, requesthandler

I would like to do `catchAsync1` but getting Error

> Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'void'

and would like to know `catchAsync3` and `catchAsync2` are correct in typescript

```
import { NextFunction, Request, RequestHandler, Response } from 'express'

export const catchAsync1 = (handler: RequestHandler) =>
  (...args: [Request, Response, NextFunction]) => handler(...args).catch(args[2])

export const catchAsync2 = (handler: RequestHandler) =>
  (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => { try { handler(req, res, next) } catch (err) { next(err) } }

export const catchAsync3 = (handler: RequestHandler) =>
  (...args: [Request, Response, NextFunction]) => { try { handler(...args) } catch (err) { args[2](err) } }
```

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Apparently your handler does not return Promise. Perhaps `async` keyword is missing there. Can you provide handler's code here?

Comment: Where are you getting the `RequestHandler` interface from?  Is this an import from express, another package, or a custom interface you created?

Comment: It is from express